# What is a better word/term for "so-called"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

I was thinking of a term that would replace "*so-called*" as it has a negative connotation like that of "*alleged*" and "*supposed*". My sentence is: *Based on the so-called great circle distance, Beijing and Shanghai are closest to the city of ...*

The reason *so-called* was added was because the term "great circle distance" sounds quite unusual because of the word "*great*" but it is an official term.

Comment: Since you're talking about the closest two points when mapped on the surface of a globe, perhaps, "Based on the cartographic great circle distance,..."  Or, since it is an actual mathematical phrase, "Based on the Great Circle Distance...," though it's unusual to capitalize mathematical terms that aren't formula names.  You could circumvent the problem with a footnote that explains what the GCD is, which would also be helpful to the reader.

Comment: 'so-called' should mean 'here is a new term for a concept that you may not know, but has drifted over, because of the common usage context, to mean 'people call it this but it's dumb or made-up or otherwise disparaging to use the term'. 'soi-disant' is the fancy French form of it and so is even more elitist and disparaging. I think 'so-called; is fine in this non-disparaging context. You may want to use just quotes, which is enough to set it off as special.

Comment: "So-named" doesn't have the connotation.

Comment: **Putative** often has a negative connotation as well: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/putative

Comment: *sometimes called...* or *also known as...* are more neutral phrases, in general. they still let you refer to a synonym or near synonym that may be known already by the reader. And even if unfamiliar, they let readers know about another commonly used name for the same thing.

Comment: @JBH While not exactly a matter of English usage, I would specifically advise against capitalizing Great Circle Distance as a solution, since GCD is also (much more commonly, in mathematics) used to abbreviate Greatest Common Denominator.

Comment: @endemic, Thanks for pointing that out.  I was refering to capitalizing the phrase and didn't even think about how my use of the acronym (which I did only to save typing space) would confuse the reader.  Cheers, that was an unintended mistake.

Comment: *Great circle distance* is a fairly common term.  Adding "so-called" makes the writer look somewhat ignorant, as in:  When you travel from England to Australia, you cross the *so-called* Tropic of Capricorn.

Comment: Thank you for all the very helpful suggestions and insights. Upon checking Wikipedia, the term includes a hyphen (Great-circle distance). Maybe this will suggest the term is not merely a circle that is "great". I might just have to use the "great-circle distance", italicize the term and eliminate "so-called".

Comment: Uh… If your sentence is: *Based on the so-called great circle distance, Beijing and Shanghai are closest to the city of ...*, why not simply leave out *… so-called...*, please?

I suggest you will find no readers at all who understand any more about what a *great circle distance* is becauase it's prefixed by *so-called…*

Comment: You ask for an adjective but there are many other ways to express this, e.g. "Based on **what geographers call** the great circle distance, Beijing and Shanghai are closest to the city of..." Compare: "Most large cities in the United States emerged where two or more modes of transportation intersect, forming what geographers call a break of bulk point." [Introduction to Human Geography by R. Adam Dastrup, MA, GISP](https://humangeography.pressbooks.com/chapter/7-1/)

Comment: As @Mitch suggested, quotation marks are often used to indicate that a specific term is being used even though it might sound unusual: *Based on the "great circle distance", Beijing and Shanghai are closest to the city of ...*

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking of a term that would replace "so-called" as it has a
> negative connotation like that of "alleged" and "supposed".

> Based on **what is known as** the great circle distance, Beijing and
> Shanghai are closest to the city of ...

or

> Based on **what is termed** the great circle distance, Beijing and
> Shanghai are closest to the city of ...

---

> The plan provides that the “actual losses” shall be multiplied by a
> modification factor to produce **what is known as** the “indicated
> risk premium.” [New York Legislative Documents, vol. 12](https://www.google.com/search?q=The%20plan%20provides%20that%20the%20%E2%80%9Cactual%20losses%E2%80%9D%20shall%20be%20multiplied%20by%20a%20modification%20factor%20to%20produce%20what%20is%20known%20as%20the%20%E2%80%9Cindicated%20risk%20premium.%E2%80%9D&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APq-WBtB8ckewKvFJ6x3b47Ei2EQAebMfQ%3A1644861492103&ei=NJgKYuTNBbiSwbkP9-KpyAI&ved=0ahUKEwjkt8PH4v_1AhU4STABHXdxCikQ4dUDCAo&uact=5&oq=The%20plan%20provides%20that%20the%20%E2%80%9Cactual%20losses%E2%80%9D%20shall%20be%20multiplied%20by%20a%20modification%20factor%20to%20produce%20what%20is%20known%20as%20the%20%E2%80%9Cindicated%20risk%20premium.%E2%80%9D&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQAFgAYH9oAHAAeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQCgAQKgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-books) (1928)

> Of the day schools, Number 1, with an average attendance of 30, is 7 0
> miles northeast of the agency, at the mouth of the Moreau, in **what
> is known as** the Blackfeet camp. [Eleventh Census of the United
> States, 1890](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Eleventh_Census_of_the_United_States_189/f6o7AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22what%20is%20known%20as%20the%22&dq=%22what%20is%20known%20as%20the%22&printsec=frontcover) [The page includes several additional examples]

> The unit of current shall be **what is known as** the international
> ampere , which is one-tenth of the unit of current of the
> centimeter-gram-second system of electromagnetic units, and is the
> practical equivalent of the unvarying current, which ... [*Circular of
> the Bureau of Standards*, Vols. 60-69, p.57](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Circular_of_the_Bureau_of_Standards/h8EjNuY784EC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22what%20is%20known%20as%20the%22&pg=PA57&printsec=frontcover)  [The page includes several
> additional examples]

> This process and its difference from **what is known as** the
> "American Process" will be briefly outlined. [American Institute of
> Architects and ‎Glenn Brown; *Quarterly Bulletin*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Quarterly_Bulletin/D3tFAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22what%20is%20known%20as%20the%22&dq=%22what%20is%20known%20as%20the%22&printsec=frontcover)  (1913)

> Those who read the Tanak today in the original languages typically
> read from **what is known as** the Masoretic Text. [Dennis Edwards;
> *What Is the Bible and How Do We Understand It?*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/What_Is_the_Bible_and_How_Do_We_Understa/kn5IEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22what%20is%20known%20as%20the%22&pg=PT24&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

---

> This is **what is termed** "the law of nations," insofar as we
> distinguish that law from the law of nature. [H. Grotius and  ‎R. Tuck
> *The Rights of War and Peace, Vol. 3, p. 1750*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Rights_of_War_and_Peace/3iVPAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22what%20is%20termed%22&dq=%22what%20is%20termed%22&printsec=frontcover) (2005)

> We are not really interested in the size of the image projected on the
> retina by the two objects, **what is termed** the proximal
> information. [I. Segev et al.; *Brain and Art*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Brain_and_Art/OMFpBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22what%20is%20termed%22&pg=PA302&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

> Dowd and Bengston suggest that ethnic minorities face **what is
> termed** the 'double jeopardy' of being aged and ethnic, and the
> consequence of their ageing experiences can be doubly negative (Dowd
> and Bengston 1978). [Titus Hjelm; *Is God Back?*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Is_God_Back/7TF2BwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22what%20is%20termed%22&pg=PT158&printsec=frontcover) (2015)